# g:datePicker with jquery UI datePicker

Tags: grails, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, grails-plugin

I am using datePicker.js to display grails datePicker. I have start and end date

```
g:datePicker class='StartDatetime' precision='minute'
```

Now I am trying to set min and max Date for the datePicker. Putting this code under ready function does not work. Is there anywhere else in the code I need to make changes to see the function work?

```
$("#StartDatetime").datepicker({
     onSelect: function (selected) {
         $("#EndDatetime_input").datepicker("option", "minDate", selected)
     }
 });

 $("#EndDatetime_input").datepicker({
     onSelect: function (selected) {
         $("#StartDatetime_input").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selected)
     }
 });
```

Comment: Are you trying to use Grails datepicker or datepicker.js ?

Comment: I am using <g:datePicker> but to display a datePicker I use jquery-ui picker.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'renderDateEditor' in src/templates/scaffolding/renderEditor.template with the following code:

```
 private renderDateEditor(domainClass, property) {
   def precision = (property.type == Date || property.type == java.sql.Date || property.type == Calendar) ? "day" : "minute";
   if (!cp) {
       return "<g:datePicker name=\"${property.name}\" precision=\"${precision}\" value=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" />"
   } else {
       if (!cp.editable) {
           return "\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}?.toString()}"
       } else {
           def out = new StringBuffer("")

           out << "<input type=\"text\" name=\"${property.name}_datepicker\" id=\"${property.name}_datepicker\" value=\"<g:formatDate date=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" formatName=\"dateonly.date.format\" />\"/>"
           out << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${property.name}_day\" id=\"${property.name}_day\" value=\"<g:formatDate date=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" format=\"dd\" />\"/>"
           out << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${property.name}_month\" id=\"${property.name}_month\" value=\"<g:formatDate date=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" format=\"MM\" />\"/>"
           out << "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"${property.name}_year\" id=\"${property.name}_year\" value=\"<g:formatDate date=\"\${${domainInstance}?.${property.name}}\" format=\"yyyy\" />\"/>"
           out << """<g:javascript>
                         \$(document).ready(function () {
                             \$("#${property.name}_datepicker").datepicker({
                                 dateFormat:'dd/MM/yy',
                                 onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
                                         var date = new Date(dateText.replace(/(\\d+).(\\d+).(\\d+)/, '\$3/\$2/\$1'));
                                         if (!isNaN(date)) {
                                             \$("#${property.name}_month").val(date.getMonth()+1);
                                             \$("#${property.name}_day").val(date.getDate());
                                             \$("#${property.name}_year").val(date.getFullYear());
                                         }
                                       },
                                 showAnim: "slide",
                                 showOptions: {direction: 'up'},
                                 showOn: "both",
                                 autoSize: true,
                                 constrainInput: true,
                                 showButtonPanel: true
                             });
                         })
                     </g:javascript>"""
           return out.toString()
       }
   }}
```